# Double.toString with two decimals

Tags: java, android, decimal, tostring

I want only 2 decimals in my code. How can i do that?

Here is my coding:

`double conta1 = ((num1*35)/100)*1.05;
 bomba1.setText(Double.toString(conta1));`

Num1=55

Well i only want to result to be 20.21 instead of 20.212500000...

How can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to round a number to n decimal places in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```
bomba1.setText(new DecimalFormat("#.##").format(conta1));
```

Comment: So i do this and then the setText?

Comment: No problem! Also, you can mark my answer as "accepted" if it helped you, marking the question as "solved".